# Angular add class to component from component css file

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to add a class to my component when I click a button. So I do it with `Renderer2` as following:

```js
this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'photo-removing');
```

The class only applies when I add the css class in a global css file. It doesn't work when I add it to the **component css file**. Any idea why does this happen?

**Update:** Here is my component html:

```html
<div *ngIf="imgMainUrl">
    <img
        [src]="imgMainUrl"
        [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height"
        [ngClass]="{ 'img-radius' : rounded }"
    >
    <i
        [pTooltip]="tooltipTxt" [tooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition"
        class="icon-close close-btn"
        (click)="removePhoto()">
    </i>
</div>
```

And css:

```css
.photo-removing {
    opacity: 0.4;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) is a much more Angular way of doing this.  On your component you would just have some logic that applies the class when the button is clicked. I can provide a more detailed answer if you'd rather do it this way.

Comment: we'd need to see more about the template structure and the css itself to understand why the it's only working when defined in the global css context.

Comment: @bryan60 Thank you. Please see the updated part.

Comment: And you’re trying to put the css in this component style sheet? Not a parent component?

Comment: @bryan60 Yes exactly. And one more thing, this component is a shared module's component which will be used in main modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ngClass]` with `*ngIf` instead

In `.html`:

```
<button (click)="buttonClicked()"></button>

<div [ngClass]={checker === true ? 'photo-removing' : ''}></div>
```

And in `.ts` file:

```
export class Home{

  checker:boolean = false;
  constructor(){}


  buttonClicked() {
   this.checker = !this.checker;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use ngClass, but I just want to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of when to use [ngClass] directive.

If you're simply using the button to toggle some variable, you can do this...

In your component.ts file:

```
public clicked: boolean = false;

click() {
     this.clicked ? false : true;
}
```

In your component.html file:

```
<button (click)="click()">Set to {{!clicked}}</button>

<div [ngClass]="{'your-class' : clicked}"></div>
```

If you really want to use a renderer, the you need to set this code in your angular app:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None.
```

By setting this value to None, you are telling Angular not to encapsulate your views. That way, the default scoping rules, isolations, and protections for styling won't apply. So, Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use ngClass, but I just want to know the reason.

Comment: Please see my updated answer ^ it has to do with view encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

## Try:-

Stackblitz Link:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-2-wdz4og?file=src/app/app.component.css

## .html

```
<div #test *ngIf="imgMainUrl">
  test
    <img
        [src]="imgMainUrl"
        [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height"
        [ngClass]="{ 'img-radius' : rounded }"
    >
<button type="button" (click)="addClass()">asasas</button>

</div>
```

## .ts

```
  @ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;
  imgMainUrl = true;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  addClass() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.test.nativeElement, 'photo-removing');
  }
```

Comment: Use #test  @ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;

Comment: I will check it ASAP.